# How to add an Islamic calendar?

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am trying to add an **Islamic** calendar.

I have tried the code below, but nothing appears on the page:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.plus.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gc = $.calendars.instance();
    var d = gc.newDate(2009, 1, 26);
    $(document).ready(
        (function ($) {
            $.calendars.calendars.islamic.prototype.regional['ar'] = {
                name: 'Islamic', // The calendar name
                epochs: ['BAM', 'AM'],
                monthNames: ['محرّم', 'صفر', 'ربيع الأول', 'ربيع الآخر أو ربيع الثاني', 'جمادى الاول', 'جمادى الآخر أو جمادى الثاني',
                'رجب', 'شعبان', 'رمضان', 'شوّال', 'ذو القعدة', 'ذو الحجة'],
                monthNamesShort: ['محرّم', 'صفر', 'ربيع الأول', 'ربيع الآخر أو ربيع الثاني', 'جمادى الاول', 'جمادى الآخر أو جمادى الثاني',
                'رجب', 'شعبان', 'رمضان', 'شوّال', 'ذو القعدة', 'ذو الحجة'],
                dayNames: ['يوم الأحد', 'يوم الإثنين', 'يوم الثلاثاء', 'يوم الأربعاء', 'يوم الخميس', 'يوم الجمعة', 'يوم السبت'],
                dayNamesShort: ['يوم الأحد', 'يوم الإثنين', 'يوم الثلاثاء', 'يوم الأربعاء', 'يوم الخميس', 'يوم الجمعة', 'يوم السبت'],
                dayNamesMin: ['يوم الأحد', 'يوم الإثنين', 'يوم الثلاثاء', 'يوم الأربعاء', 'يوم الخميس', 'يوم الجمعة', 'يوم السبت'],
                dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd', // See format options on BaseCalendar.formatDate
                firstDay: 6, // The first day of the week, Sun = 0, Mon = 1, ...
                isRTL: true // True if right-to-left language, false if left-to-right
            };
        })
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Have you read the "usage"-part? http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html

Comment: i have read it and make the steps as you see in my code

Comment: how can i add it in my html code??